# Xdebug not working PhpStorm + Apache (But works PHP Webserver)

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, xdebug

I have always used the PHP built in webserver for quick testing of websites locally.

This works great. Xdebug works in PhpStorm without issue.

/however/ I need to use Apache for a new project. Everything is working locally. However PhpStorm no longer no longer triggers breakpoints on the Apache version, still works fine with PHP webserver.

phpinfo() and debug validation on PhpStorm both show everything is fine. So I am quite confused! Is there something on Apache side I need to change?

Comment: I bet the PHP you use in Apache uses a different `php.ini` file and therefore your XDEBUG changes in the `php.ini` file are not there

Comment: Apache server is showing xdebug as loaded though

Comment: But unless you CONFIGURE it in the `php.ini` folder, it wont do anything

Comment: The Apache and PHP Webserver are using the identical php.ini.... unless I’m missing something. But seeing the same phpinfo() data for settings I change.

Comment: Please share your xdebug config as seen in `phpinfo()` run by that web server.

Comment: @Sebter 1) Show whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured for Apache 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug (using Apache served page) and share the log file.